# High Sierra - KDP is not listening for new connections

Tags: macos, debugging, xnu

I created a setup of a guest virtual machine High Sierra which runs by VirtualBox.

I KDP on both guest and host. 
I copied the development version of XNU from the KDP directory into the kernel directory on both guest and host.

I read that VirtualBox does not have the implementation for NVRAM so I had to use the following command to setup the kernel boot arguments for kernel debugging.

```
VBoxManage setextradata “your virtual machine name>" "VBoxInternal2/EfiBootArgs" [here go the kernel boot arguments]
```

However, I tried the combination of Command+Option+Control+Shift+Esc however it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, Command+Option+Control+Shift+Esc has a special meaning in hardware on Mac laptops. For a VM, you probably want to set the `0x8000` bit in the `debug` kernel argument and just send an ACPI power event to trigger the debugger instead.

I can't say if this will work in VirtualBox though as I haven't used that to do kernel debugging for a number of years.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method for attaching to a VM is using DTrace:

`sudo dtrace -w -n "BEGIN { breakpoint(); }"`

Then from the host you can:

`kdp-remote <vm-ip>`